# Combine code to shorten it

Tags: ms-access

I got the following code in my form:

```
             txtFrontname.Locked = False
             txtFrontname.BorderStyle = 4
             txtFrontname.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)

             txtLastname.Locked = False
             txtLastname.BorderStyle = 4
             txtLastname.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)

             txtAdress.Locked = False
             txtAdress.BorderStyle = 4
             txtAdress.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
```

Is there a way to combine this code? So my code gets shorter?
Like all .Locked in 1 line, all .Borderstyle in 1 line and all .BorderColor in 1 line?

Comment: I think this question belongs to code review section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Select Case*:

```
Dim Control As Access.Control

For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
       Select Case Control.Name
            Case _
                "txtFrontname", _
                "txtLastname", _
                "txtAdress"

                With Control
                    .Locked = False
                    .BorderStyle = 4
                    .BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
                End With
        End Select
    End If
Next

Set Control = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I get an error:

Compile error: Syntax mistake

Comment: It's a snippet. You need some _Dims_ as well.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge kinda stops here